# Android resize image to fit screen size

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in Android that loads an image from an URL, the image size that is loaded is 500 * 500.
When the image is loaded on a small screen it fits all the width of the screen and the height is very acceptable. However on a larger screen the image gets very very small, why? And how can I solve this?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/items_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/items_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross_blank" />
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshots from both screens and the entire xml? Problem could be in the containing layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the width and height to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill parent"
```

And put your `ImageView` inside a `linearlayout` and set the width and height of layout also to `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Depended on your layout, change to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```